# Van Kampen diagram, Van Kampen lemma

Tags: group-theory

Question: On the website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Kampen_diagram#cite_note-LS-9,

It is given a Van Kampen diagram over the presentation $G=\langle a,b|aba^{-1}b^{-1}    \rangle$ whose boundary label is the word: $w=b^{-1}b^{3}a^{-1}b^{-2}ab^{-1}ba^{-1}ab^{-1}ba^{-1}a$. By the Van Kampen's lemma, it must be that $w=1$ in G. How can we show that indeed $w=1$ in G? I really appreciate any explanatory answer here.

Comment: Start by simplifying factors like $a^{-1}a$ and $b^{-1}b$, which are equal to the identity.

Comment: When I start by simplifying factors like $a^{-1}a$ and $b^{-1}b$, which are equal to the identity, I get the word $bba^{-1}b^{-1}b^{-1}a$ which is neither a relator or even a conjugate of a relator, so I do not know how to simply further in order to get 1.

Comment: @Dijnola You know $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$, so $ba^{-1}b^{-1}=a^{-1}$. Your word $w$ then becomes $ba^{-1}b^{-1}a$. Applying the same thing again, you have $a^{-1}a=1$.

Comment: @rbird, Just an alternative if that is true: when the word $w$ becomes $ba^{-1}b^{-1}a$, we know that this must be 1 as the set of relators contain the inverse and all cyclic shifts of $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Comment: @Dijnola Yes, that also works.

Comment: @rbird, OK sounds good. Is there any book with or without solutions I can use to solve problems related to Van Kampen diagram and small cancelation conditions like finding pieces, relators and whether a given presentation satisfies C'($\lambda$) or $C(p)$?

Comment: I learned algebraic topology from Allen Hatcher's book (freely available on his website [here](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/)), but I don't think this has many problems like you want. A book on presentations of groups would probably be better.

Comment: @Dijnola The book Geometry of Defining Relations in Groups by Ol'shanskii is a very good reference.